# Issues with the Label in tkiner

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I've been working in a code for some weeks, just trying to start with python and I've found a strange problem when I try to update the values in a top level window from Tk, the previous value of the label seems to be in the background of the label and I must remove it, here some pics to show the problem, thank you for reading my problem and also for all your help.

link to the pic:
http://oi57.tinypic.com/e6u2c2.jpg

PD: it is in spanish
PD2: if the code is needed I can paste the segments of the code that generates this issue.

Comment: Problem solved, I'm sorry if this question was stupid.

Comment: Could you please either post an answer with how you solved your problem or delete the question? As it is now, this is not helpful to anyone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was generated when I hitted a button in the Tkinter interface, and every time it generated a new Label, this new Label displayed the updated information, but the older ones was still in the frame, then when I changed the value of the StringVar to something shorter I still could see the last Label there, the solution was to destroy the last Label when I update the value of the StringVar socitaed to the Label, then I get what I needed.

The code that generated the error:

```
        self.varTotal = StringVar()
        self.lblTotal = Label(self.master, textvariable = self.varTotal)
        self.varTotalLetras = StringVar()
        self.lblTotalLetras = Label(self.master, textvariable = self.varTotalLetras)
...
        self.varTotal.set(total)
        self.varTotalLetras.set(num2words(int(total), lang = 'es').upper() + " PESOS.")
```

Then every time when I clicked the button a new instance of the Label seemed to be created.

And My solution was to delete the current instance of the Labels and then create another one.